# Was the "bell, book, and candle" used for all ferendae sententiae excommunications?

Tags: catholicism, excommunication

When the "[bell, book, and candle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell,_book,_and_candle)" ritual was still used by the Catholic church, was it used in all *ferendae sententiae* excommunications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Pontificale Romanum*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5915) rubrics for the [*Ordo Excommunicandi*](https://www.liturgialatina.org/pontificale/101.htm) distinguish three types of excommunication:

1. **Minor**
   "A minor excommunication is contracted by mere participation with the excommunicate, and from such a simple Priest can absolve without a sworn statement;"
   <sub>"Minor excommunicatio contrahitur per solam participationem cum excommunicato, et a tali potest simplex Sacerdos absolvere absque juratoria cautione;"</sub>
2. **Major**
   is one "which the Bishop promulgates by a reading a written decree"
   <sub>"quam Pontifex per sententiam scriptam legendo promulgat"</sub>
3. **Anathema**
   is said when "the solemn excommunication for graver offenses must be done"
   <sub>"solemnis excommunicatio pro gravioribus culpis fieri debet"</sub>

The anathema is the one that includes candles.

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between a minor excommunication and a regular mortal sin? It sounds like either removes the sinner from a state of grace and must be absolved by a priest?

Comment: @Someone [Excommunication](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33457) is the most severe [ecclesiastical censure](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32405) ("A penalty by which a baptized person, gravely delinquent and obstinate, is deprived of certain spiritual benefits until he gives up his obstinacy."). Mortal sin is the loss of sanctifying grace. Not all mortal sins are excommunicable offenses.